# jquery background change / keep color from previous page

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make a site with each page fading in a new background color.

So far I am just using document ready and adding a class to the html tag.

When you click to go to a new page... It leaves, say "blue" and goes to the new page "yellow."

When It arrives at "yellow" - it reads the standard html background-color, which I have set to "Red," and then proceeds to add the yellow class.  ( so from blue / cut to red / fade to yellow )  instead of the desired effect of blue / fade to yellow.

What I would like to know, is if there is a way reference or keep the background-color from the previous page as a starting point.  I have a test page here.  In chrome you never see red.  so view this in fire fox.

http://derekthomaswood.com/dev/background-change

I can think of some ways to deal with this if I was using ajax... but on this project I am trying to keep ajax out of it.  (but I am open to anything you can think of)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you are targetting HTML5 browsers, you could use local storage.  Or you could use cookies or URL variables or URL hashtags to pass the information between pages.

Comment: If you're not targetting HTML5 browsers, cookies would probably make sense. If you're using a server side script like PHP, you could read the color from the cookie and apply the style directly.

Comment: I will be theming this into WordPress, so I will be using php.  I don't have much experience with cookies.  Do you have any specific resources you suggest ?  Also, there will be more then 2 pages, just for the record.

Comment: Why dont you add the color parameter in the PHP $_POST or $_GET array and then check it on page load and manipulate the background color accordingly?